# Does placing an address tag inside of a section tag conform to html5 guidelines?

Tags: html

Is placing the address tag within a section like this following the html5 guidelines?

```
<section id="address">
    <header>
       <h3><span style="color: #f3d351;">Call Us: 1-800-576-7449 </span></h3>
    </header>
       <address>
          <p>4660 N. University Drive<br /> Lauderhill, FL 33351 United States</p>
       </address>
</section>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use cases of some of the new HTML5 elements may still be open to interpretation, as W3C typically just has "suggested use cases" or something similar for them.

The `<section>` tag's [W3C wiki page](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section) does, however, have a specific use case applicable to you:

> A Web site's home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news items, and contact information.

Obviously the [`<address>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/address) element should contain some sort of contact infromation.

Given your markup and the information on the linked wiki pages, I would say the placement of `<address>` inside of `<section>` is not only allowed, but one of the encouraged use cases.

I'm not entirely sure the `<p>` tag inside of the `<address>` element is necessary, or completely semantically correct.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine except for the fact that the `address` element is not for arbitrary postal addresses: [address element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-address-element) so you could simply use `p` instead.

Comment: what do you mean by arbitrary? If I just use the <p> then I'm not marking up my address at all? right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an address tag inside of a section tag, there is nothing wrong with that. However, you cannot place a section tag inside of an address tag. This [MDN article on address](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/address) has more information.

The one caveat is that you are using section as a generic container. It is suggested to use a `div` if you are going to just be using the element as a placeholder.